# scale text size

Tags: fontsize

I'm stuck with a somewhat unusual problem. The poster template that I have to use outputs A4 pages, while the final poster will be A0. That means, I have to scale everything by a factor of 4 (linearly). I think this is done such that "normal" font sizes are readable on the A0 poster from a distance. The problem is that they are actually much too large and I want to shrink them. I do not seem to be able to set a small enough font. My preferred solution would be to scale a bigger font. That would normally not be desirable because it is better to use a font that was designed to be smaller, but remember that in this case the fonts will be scaled back when printing.

My current solution uses something along the lines of `\fontsize{5mm}{6mm}\selectfont` to set a custom font size. This only sets the font size of most of the text and not of the text for: math, siunitx package and the bibliography. If I set the font size using `\small` or similar, I do get the same fontsize everywhere. Is it possible to mimic one of these commands, but with a custom size?

Comment: Which `\documentclass` do you use? For example `\documentclass[a0]{sciposter}` supports A0. Can you add a MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?

Comment: Maybe you can use A2 paper and then double the size.

Comment: I use a university specific class that only supports A4. I don't like how they did it, but that is what I have to work with unfortunately (unless I want to rebuild the entire layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [koma-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)s `scrartcl` documentclass. This class provides scaling for the fonts, although I'm not sure about the internals of this package. Currently I use `\documentclass[fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}` to set the font size to 6pt, but any LaTeX length is accepted. Luckily my template was included as a package, not as a documentclass and as such I was able to use this method.